# NaN return value from function Javascript || Function Execution Order

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

Newbie in Javascript here, and after hours digging trough other questions I'm not quite sure how to explain this to be honest, but i'll give it my best, hopefully you'll be able to help me.

HTML:

```
<div id='header'> <h1> Pastel Land </h1> </div>

    <div id='container'>

        <div id='readyContainer'> 

            <h3> This game will start in </h3>
            <h1 id='readySeconds'> </h1>

        </div>

        <div id='shape'> </div>

    </div>

    <div id='features'>

        <button id='start'> START </button> 
        <button id='stop'> STOP </button>

        <p id='timeBox'></p>
        <p id='timeAverageBox'></p>
    </div>

    <div id='testbox'> </div>
```

FULL SCRIPT:

```
document.getElementById('start').onclick = function () { 
        document.getElementById('readyContainer').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('readySeconds').innerHTML = '3'
        setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('readySeconds').innerHTML = '2'}, 1000);
        setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('readySeconds').innerHTML = '1'}, 2000);


        setTimeout(readyAlert,3000);
        setTimeout(displayShape, 3000);


        var style = document.getElementById('shape').style;

        var el = document.getElementById('shape');

        el.addEventListener("click", a, false);
        el.addEventListener("click", b, false);

        function a() {

            style.display = "none";
            displayShapeDelay(); // calls the delay function
        }

        function b() { 

            end = new Date().getTime();  // saves time when clicked

            var time = (end - start)/1000 ; // calculates interval from shape creation until click

            document.getElementById('timeBox').innerHTML = time + 's';

            return time;

        }

        document.getElementById('testbox').innerHTML = b();


        function readyAlert() {
                document.getElementById('readyContainer').style.display = 'none';

        }   

        function getRandomColor() {

        var hex = ["#96ceb4", "#ffeead", "#ff6f69", "#ffcc5c", "#88db8b0", "#528491"];

        var color = hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)]; // generates integer numbers [0,5], selects indexed item from hex

        return color;

        }



        function displayShape () {

            var percentages = [];

            for (var i=0; i<4; i++){ // generates a list with 4 different random integer values [5,60]

                percentages.push((Math.floor(Math.random() * 61) + 5));

            }

            var width = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 61) + 5); // generates integer numbers [5,60]

            var shapeRand = Math.random()

            if (shapeRand < 0.3) { // circle
                style.borderRadius = "50%";

            } else if (shapeRand >= 0.3 && shapeRand < 0.6) { // random shape
                style.borderTopLeftRadius = percentages[0] + "%";
                style.borderBottomRightRadius = percentages[1] + "%";
                style.borderTopRightRadius = percentages[2] + "%";
                style.borderBottomLeftRadius = percentages[3] + "%";
            } else { // square
                style.borderRadius = "0%";
            }

            //general shape styles
            style.width = width + "%";
            style.height = width + "%";
            style.display = "block";
            style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
            style.top = percentages[0] + "%";
            style.left = percentages[3] + "%";

            start = new Date().getTime(); // saves time when shape is created

            console.log(width);
            console.log(getRandomColor());
            console.log(shapeRand);
            console.log(percentages);


        }

        function displayShapeDelay () { // calls the main function with a delay between ]0s,2s[
            setTimeout(displayShape, Math.random() * 2000);
        }


        document.getElementById('stop').onclick = function() {


        }

    }
```

Before I had this:

My goal was to return var 'time' to the global scope, so that I could use it to create an array of each value created with each click. I've realised that this was not possible from an anonymous function.

```
document.getElementById('shape').onclick = function() { // calls the delay function

            style.display = "none";

            displayShapeDelay();

            end = new Date().getTime();

            time = (end - start)/1000 ;

            document.getElementById('timeBox').innerHTML = time + 's';

            return time

        }
```

So this is the code I have now :

```
var shapeClick = document.getElementById('shape');

        shapeClick.addEventListener("click", a, false);
        shapeClick.addEventListener("click", b, false);

        function a() {

            style.display = "none";
            displayShapeDelay(); // calls the delay function
        }

        function b() { 

            end = new Date().getTime();  // saves time when clicked

            var time = (end - start)/1000 ; // calculates interval from shape creation until click

            document.getElementById('timeBox').innerHTML = time + 's';

            return time;

        }

        document.getElementById('testbox').innerHTML = b();
```

Now, there's a couple of issues with this:

1- I can't seem to understand why the two "time divs" are assigned values after pressing the Start button. This means that function b is running, but shouldn't it only be running after the onClick event?

2- In the 'first-round' I understand why both values show up as NaN, since there's no value assigned to the variable "time" yet. But after the onClick event executes, the 'time' value assigned inside 'timeBox' works fine, but the one called outside the function doesn't. Isn't "return time" inside function b, supposed to be returning the value of the "time" variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add your HTML?

Comment: 1: the reason the b() is running is because of this line "document.getElementById('testbox').innerHTML = b();". its on the global scope i assume, so when the code loads b() gets executed right away..You'd be better off putting that in the b(), so "document.getElementById('testbox').innerHTML = time;"

Comment: 2: b() returns time, and i'm assuming your talking about the testbox element isn't updating with time, that would because "document.getElementById('testbox').innerHTML = b();" only runs once, on initial load. It doesn't update when b() is run again. looking at my other comment would fix that.

Comment: @whipdancer HTML added.

Comment: @flapjack17 Thanks. So, I think I got what you mean by the code only running on load. But the problem is that I can't put it inside b(), my goal is overtime b() runs assign the variable 'time' to an array outside b, so that I can accumulate each value. (P.S: I've tried it anyway, and it doesn't even input content to div anymore)

Comment: What do you expect to see or what is the result you expect?  As the code is, it is not clear what you want to happen or what you are trying to do. I understand your question about seeing `NaN`, but I think (as @Traktor53 pointed out) that you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: Answer updated to resolve the code structure issue. Found out Pastel Land is a bit like the Whac-a-Mole arcade amusement. @whipdancer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pastel Land

The `onclick` function is serving as the outer function of a whole lot of code which execute when the start button is clicked. Also all of it runs every time the start button is clicked: click start multiple times quickly to see a problem.  .

Inside #start.onclick() you have

```
document.getElementById('testbox').innerHTML = b();
```

in mainline click handler code: it is not inside another function and runs when the start button is clicked. Since `end` has not been set yet, the result for `time` is `NaN`. The code inside `function b` set the content of  #timebox as well.

If you run the code in strict mode the javascript engine will tell you that `end` has not been declared. It should be - even if requred in global scope.

As an aside, fyi, `Date.now()` avoids the need to create and discard a Date object and is equivalent to `new Date().getTime()`.

I suggest reworking the code to move the logic of Pastel Land outside the start button click handler, and have the click handler call into the main application code as needed but only contain logic specific to the start action itself. If you want to avoid polluting global scope you can include all the code in an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) (immediately invoked function expression) that would serve the same scope containment provision that the click handler is currently providing. Kindly, I think the code in its current state is presenting an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :-)

---

### The Game

A restructured version of Pastel Land is shown below for several reasons: you've had time to try it yourself, most of the code is yours and the remainder demonstrates what was meant by the suggestion. And it's a very silly game that deserves to be played!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PastelLand</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>

window.addEventListener("load", function() // an IIFE
{"use strict"

   // Pastel Land

    var running = false;
    var start = 0;
    var end = 0;
    var times = []; // calculating average still to do
    var el, style;

    function getRandomColor() {
        var hex = ["#96ceb4", "#ffeead", "#ff6f69", "#ffcc5c", "#88db8b0", "#528491"];
        var color = hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)]; // generates integer numbers [0,5], selects indexed item from hex
        return color;
    }

    function displayShape () {
        var percentages = [];

        for (var i=0; i<4; i++){ // generates a list with 4 different random integer values [5,60]
            percentages.push((Math.floor(Math.random() * 61) + 5));
        }
        var width = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 61) + 5); // generates integer numbers [5,60]
        var shapeRand = Math.random()

        if (shapeRand < 0.3) { // circle
            style.borderRadius = "50%";

        } else if (shapeRand >= 0.3 && shapeRand < 0.6) { // random shape
            style.borderTopLeftRadius = percentages[0] + "%";
            style.borderBottomRightRadius = percentages[1] + "%";
            style.borderTopRightRadius = percentages[2] + "%";
            style.borderBottomLeftRadius = percentages[3] + "%";
        } else { // square
            style.borderRadius = "0%";
        }

        //general shape styles
        style.width = width + "px";
        style.height = width + "px";
        style.position = "absolute"
        style.display = "block";
        style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
        style.top = percentages[0] + "%";
        style.left = percentages[3] + "%";

        start = Date.now(); // saves time when shape is created

        console.log(width);
        console.log(getRandomColor());
        console.log(shapeRand);
        console.log(percentages);
    }

    function displayShapeDelay () { // calls the main function with a delay between ]0s,2s[
        setTimeout(displayShape, Math.random() * 2000);
    }

    function readyAlert() {
            document.getElementById('readyContainer').style.display = 'none';
    }

    function userFound() {
        style.display = "none";
        end = Date.now(); 
        var time = (end - start)/1000 ; // calculates interval from shape creation until click
        document.getElementById('timeBox').innerHTML = time + 's';
        displayShapeDelay(); // calls the delay function
        times.push( time); // saves time user took to find shape
    }

    function userStart() {

        if( running)
            return;
        running = true;
        document.getElementById('readyContainer').style.display = 'block';  
        document.getElementById('readySeconds').innerHTML = '3'
        setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('readySeconds').innerHTML = '2'}, 1000);
        setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('readySeconds').innerHTML = '1'}, 2000);
        setTimeout(readyAlert,3000);
        setTimeout(displayShape, 3000);
        times.length = 0;  // reset times array
    }

    function userStop() {
        running = false;
        style.display="none"
    }
    function init() {
        el = document.getElementById('shape');
        style = el.style;
        el.addEventListener("click", userFound, false);
        document.getElementById('start').onclick=userStart;
        document.getElementById('stop').onclick=userStop;    
    }
    return init; // window load listener
}());
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='header'> <h1> Pastel Land </h1> </div>
<div id='container'>
    <div id='readyContainer'>
        <h3> This game will start in </h3>
        <h1 id='readySeconds'> </h1>
    </div>
    <div id='shape' style="height:40px;width:40px;"></div>
</div>
<div id='features'>
    <button id='start'> START </button> 
    <button id='stop'> STOP </button>
    <p id='timeBox'></p>
    <p id='timeAverageBox'></p>
</div>
<div id='testbox'> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Calculation and display of averages and minor changes to page presentation remain to be done (I'm not coding them!). Units for width and height were changed from "%" to "px" (pixels) and "position: absolute;" added to shape.style. Functions `a` and `b` were combined into function `userFound`.  Code involving "testbox" was omitted. The IIEF returns an initialization function to be executed after window load.

---

**Notes**

`userStart` and `userStop` click event handlers were defined using named [function declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) instead of coding them as anonymous functions in the parameter lists of calls to other functions.

Declared function names refer to the function object created by their declaration. Hence setting the value of an element's `onclick` attribute to a function name works because the attribute requires a function object value. Setting `onclick` to the undefined value returned from calling one of the handlers would not work.

The start/stop handlers could have been registered as "click" event listeners, using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of  element `onclick` values.

The `init` function is *not* called by the IIFE. The IIFE itself is called when the

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // IIFE code }() );
```

statement is executed in the head section of the page. All function objects  declared at top level within the IIFE are created at this time. The function returned by the IIFE, `init`, is registered as a listener for later execution, after all DOM elements have been created for the HTML body and the window load event fires.

If you call `userStart` from `init` after other `el` and `style` have been initialized, the game will start. Although `userStart` is normally called in response to clicking the start button, it will still behave the same if called by other means.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, really appreciate you going the extra mile. I just found some time to tinker with your code and have a couple of follow ups on the init function, if you don't mind. Why is it that you only need the function name for the start event handler? And why does the function starts running on load if I use "userStart()" instead, even without clicking start? I understand that the init function gets called by the IIEF, but shouldn't the onclick events' functions be called, well... onclick. Once again, thank you!